# How to use a jQuery Spoiler

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I found this [jQuery Spoiler on GitHub](https://github.com/le717/jquery-spoiler) and I'm tring to get it work on [my site](https://en.unicstack.com/data/details-id=11) (The *"Share"* button should spoile the share buttons below), but it doesn't. The problem is I'm very new to jQuery, threfore I've no idea why. I'm using WP, so I include them via the function.php

```
function bresponZive_themepacific_tpcrn_scripts_method() {

    wp_enqueue_script ('spoiler', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.spoiler.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script ('spoiler-init',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/spoiler-init.js', array('jquery'));

}
```

My HTML setup:

```
<div class="a2a-share-counter spoiler" data-spoiler-link="1">
<div class="share-bar-inner spoiler-content" data-spoiler-link="1">
```

The spoiler-init.js file looks like this, it should activate the jQuery Spoiler.

```
(function($) {

  $(".spoiler").spoiler({
    paddingValue: 20
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're including `spoiler-init.js` in the head but your code assumes the jQuery selector would be valid at that point (which it may not be).

Try this:

```
(function($) {
  $(function () { //Equivalent to $(document).ready
      $(".spoiler").spoiler({
        paddingValue: 20
      });
   });    
})(jQuery);
```